# Why doesn't this program run properly under Clang or GCC?

Tags: c++, regex, clang++

I'm trying to run [CPPReference's regex_search example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string lines[] = {"Roses are #ff0000",
                           "violets are #0000ff",
                           "all of my base are belong to you"};

    std::regex color_regex("#([a-f0-9]{2})"
                        "([a-f0-9]{2})"
                        "([a-f0-9]{2})");

    for (const auto &line : lines) {
        std::cout << line << ": " 
                  << std::regex_search(line, color_regex) << '\n';
    }   

    std::smatch color_match;
    for (const auto &line : lines) {
        std::regex_search(line, color_match, color_regex);
        std::cout << "matches for '" << line << "'\n";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < color_match.size(); ++i)
            std::cout << i << ": " << color_match[i] << '\n';
    }   
}
```

This program compiles with Clang++ 3.4-1ubuntu3 and GCC 4.8.2, but running it immediately gives this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error
Aborted (core dumped)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21541199/regex-search-in-cppreference-throw-error) indicated that the problem was one with GCC, but compiling with Clang produces the same problem. Even explicitly passing in the library at each step with the command:

```
clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++11 -H -c regex.cpp -o object.o && clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++ object.o -o regex
```

causes the error at runtime, despite the fact that the last lines of the first command's output are:

```
.. /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/regex_constants.h
.. /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/regex_error.h
.. /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/regex_cursor.h
.. /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/regex_nfa.h
... /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/regex_nfa.tcc
.... /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/regex
.. /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/regex_compiler.h
.. /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/regex_grep_matcher.h
... /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/regex_grep_matcher.tcc
.... /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/regex
.. /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/regex.h
```

...which would indicate that the appropriate headers are present on my system.

Comment: You need GCC >= 4.9 to use regex. Its not fully implemented before that version.

Comment: In C++ regexes, is `[a-f]` required to match exactly the set of characters `a`, `b`, `c`, ... `f` in a way that is independent of locale?

Comment: I have GCC 4.9.2 and your code runs without any error...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still use the incomplete `gcc` standard library implementation, you even explicitly tell `clang` to use it with `-stdlib=libstdc++`.

The standard library implementation that comes with `clang` is `libc++`, you thus need `-stdlib=libc++` instead.

Comment: Not to mention that GCC 4.8's reges implementation is incomplete and buggy.

Comment: When I run `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -H -c regex.cpp -o object.o && clang++ -stdlib=libc++ object.o -o regex`, I get this message: `regex.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^
. ./regex
1 error generated.`

Comment: Never mind, I needed to run `sudo apt-get install libc++-dev`; it works fine, now.